# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services, enterprise-library

In my Windows Service project, I have refereed Enterprise Library Caching **5.0.505**, but I get the following error on service start

```
Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    File name: 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

App.Config

```
<configSections>

    <section name="cachingConfiguration" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>


<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Cache Manager">
    <cacheManagers>
      <add name="Cache Manager" 
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
           expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" 
           maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="50000" 
           numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="1000" 
           backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" />
    </cacheManagers>
    <backingStores>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
           name="NullBackingStore" />
    </backingStores>
  </cachingConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs when the referenced assembly doesn't match with the one in the `bin` folder.

Try adding this to your `.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.505.0" newVersion="5.0.505.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But how can that be, I have refereed throw nugget, I double checked the properties of those refereed dlls

Comment: Are you working with multiple projects? If so, you need to check if all the projects are referencing the same version.

Comment: Yes, there is a dependent project which is using "5.0.414.0", but since this service project is using latest version, i thought this would take the precedence?

Comment: If in your project references, the assembly is marked with "Specific Version" = true, no precedence will be taken. This is valid to the dependent project too.